# Prove that their product function $h(x,y)=f(x,y) \cdot g(x,y)$ also satisfies Laplace's equation

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $w=f(x,y)$ and $u=g(x,y)$ be two real functions of the real variables $x$ and $y$ which both satisfy Laplace's equation. Prove that their product function $h(x,y)=f(x,y) \cdot g(x,y)$ also satisfies Laplace's equation if it does or give a counterexample if this is not generally true.

Assume that $\Delta f=\frac{\,d^2f}{dx^2}+\frac{\,d^2f}{dy^2}=0$ and $\Delta g=\frac{\,d^2g}{dx^2}+\frac{\,d^2g}{dy^2}=0$. We need to show that $\Delta h=\frac{\,d^2h}{dx^2}+\frac{\,d^2h}{dy^2}=0$, where $h(x,y)=f(x,y)\cdot g(x,y)$.

$$\frac{\,dh}{\,dx}=\frac{\,df}{\,dx}g(x,y)+\frac{\,dg}{\,dx}f(x,y)$$

$$\frac{\,d^2h}{\,dx^2}=\frac{\,d^2f}{\,dx^2}g(x,y)+2\frac{\,df\,dg}{\,dx^2}+\frac{\,d^2g}{\,dx^2}f(x,y)$$

Similarly, we find

$$\frac{\,d^2h}{\,dy^2}=\frac{\,d^2f}{\,dy^2}g(x,y)+2\frac{\,df\,dg}{\,dy^2}+\frac{\,d^2g}{\,dy^2}f(x,y)$$

So

$$\Delta h=\frac{\,d^2f}{\,dx^2}g(x,y)+2\frac{\,df\,dg}{\,dx^2}+\frac{\,d^2g}{\,dx^2}f(x,y)\frac{\,d^2f}{\,dy^2}g(x,y)+2\frac{\,df\,dg}{\,dy^2}+\frac{\,d^2g}{\,dy^2}f(x,y)=(\frac{\,d^2f}{\,dx^2}+\frac{\,d^2f}{\,dy^2})g(x,y)+2(\frac{\,df}{\,dx}\frac{\,dg}{\,dx}+\frac{\,df}{\,dy}\frac{\,dg}{\,dy^2})+(\frac{\,d^2g}{\,dx^2}+\frac{\,d^2g}{\,dy^2})f(x,y)=2(\frac{\,df}{\,dx}\frac{\,dg}{\,dx}+\frac{\,df}{\,dy}\frac{\,dg}{\,dy^2})$$

With the information given these last two partials are not necessarily zero all the time.
What is an explicit counterexample that will help me show that my claim above is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is an example that makes one of those terms non-zero, right?

So $f=g=x$ should do it.

Also, your notation is a bit strange to me, for example I would write

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}x}$$ instead of $$\frac{\mathrm{d}f \mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}x^2}.$$

This shows that those two derivatives are multiplied together.

Comment: I took your comment about my formatting into account. I have made neccessary changes. Thanks for the help!!!